# find the largest and the second largest numbers out of five numbers in C programming

Tags: c

I want to write a C program which can find the largest and the second-largest numbers among the five numbers.
that would be great if I could've written this only using if-else operators.

like this(but it should be 5 numbers and it should find the second largest number)

```
int main() {
  int a, b, c;
  int min, max;
  printf("Uc sayi girin: ");
  scanf("%d%d%d", & a, & b, & c);
  printf("Ortalama: %f\n", (a + b + c) / 3.0);

  if (a < b) {
    min = a;
    max = b;
  } else {
    min = b;
    max = a;
  }
  if (c < min)
    min = c;
  else if (c > max)
    max = c;

  printf("The smallest number: %d\n", min);
  printf("The greatest number: %d\n", max);

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Firstly you should wrap your numbers into a collection, like an array. From there you can approach this in many different ways. A common solution, if you know the size of the array will be small, is to sort the array. The largest and second largest numbers will be the last and second to last elements of the array, assuming you sorted in increasing order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier to do this in a `for` loop;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int a[5] = { 2, 4, -3, -5, 9 };
  int m0 = 0x80000000; // set to min
  int m1 = 0x80000000; // set to min
  int t; // temporary var

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (m1 < a[i]) {
      m1 = a[i];

      if (m0 < m1) {
        t = m0;
        m0 = m1;
        m1 = t;
      }
    }
  }

  printf("max = %d second max = %d\n", m0, m1);

  return 0;
}
```